# Project inside Eclipse runs 42 times faster using maven

Tags: eclipse, performance, maven

You wont trust my words so i post a image. I have radical time differences between eclipse and maven.

[image: Eclipse slow???]

My CPU is i7-4790K@4GHz and 32gb Ram DDR3-2800 (PC3-22400U).
Any idea how to solve this problem?

(Please do not answer *question to life the universe and everything*)

**EDIT**: I measured the execution time of single methods, they constantly lag near factor 42 more using eclipse.

Comment: Eclipse is an IDE. It _integrates_ many tools (for debugging and so on). Command line just runs things: call Maven, which calls Java, and you're done. Obviously, this has an impact. This is even more visible on startup (I suppose the gap is lesser once both JVM have warmed up). Unfortunately, I am not sure you can do something about it. Eclipse is for developing (and great at debugging... most of the time), but is ill-fit if you want a precise evaluation of the performances of your future application.

Comment: @Chop This are my plugins: Subversive, Findbugs and Checkstyle. Serioulsy: This does not make impact!

Comment: You have so many more plugins! A virgin Eclipse is 60 or 70 Mb, yours was probably around 300 or 360 Mb. Eclipse alone is only a plugin platform, that's why you download it pre-packaged. But that's not the purpose here: your Eclipse (assuming the J2EE edition) comes with much Java tooling, debugger, ... I don't even know how many arguments it passes to the JVM (remote debugging?). Also, are you using the embedded JVM or is it the same as your command line? JRE implementation may have an impact too.

Comment: @Chop Finally you mean its common to be **42 times more slow** using Eclipse? I will never accept this! **42 times!!**

Comment: No need to get bold on me, I'm only trying to give some insight. I don't develop Eclipse. I am not saying this is normal, and 42 times is obviously excessive. **Startup** is 42 times more slow. What about execution? Have you tried measuring execution time for some methods? Have you tried several times (JVM warm-up is also something, or maybe your IDE was still loading and spent time multitasking, ...). You are asking for a generic answer without supplying any specifics nor results for tests other than startup. Comments often begin with _What have you tried?_ or downvotes in this kind of cases.

Comment: Finally, if you are not satisfied with Eclipse, there are also many other tools for Maven projects. I know many developers who are more happy with IntelliJ or Netbeans (which integrate Maven projects without the need for a plugins (yes, Eclipse uses m2e for Maven integration, so you have that plugin at least)) and using the pom file as a descriptor instead of generating a `.project`.

Comment: @Chop The startup is the execution. Eclipse and Maven run very fast, only the project i work on has different speeds. I had to work years using Intellij IDEA and Netbeans, both make absurd syntax proposals, but i use netbeans often for swing applications.

Comment: I'm sorry. I have no more ideas, that's why I did not submit an answer. I hope someone will have something more. (Just out of curiousity, is the project source available publicly?)

Comment: @Chop not yet, but will come soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After six hours it look like its fixed, i dont know why.

[image]

Very weird!